# I have a Problem with Spring Web Api; I always get status code 404 for the right path

Tags: java, spring

I try to consume the endpoint over Intellij but I get a 404 status code every time I tried it with the GET endpoint:

> http://localhost:8080/api/countries/string

```
package de.luca.test.controller;

import de.luca.test.model.Country;
import de.luca.test.repository.CountryRepo;
import de.luca.test.service.CountryService;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path ="/api/countries")
public class CountryController {
    private CountryService countryService;

    @Autowired
    public CountryController(CountryService countryService) {
        this.countryService = countryService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<Country> getAllCountries() {
        Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CountryController.class);
        log.info("Array groeße: " + this.getAllCountries().size());
        return this.countryService.getAllCountries();
    }

    @GetMapping("/string")
    public String getString() {
        return this.countryService.getString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't try to game the system by adding useless fluff at the end of your post. That limitation should have told you that you're giving us too much code vs the description of your problem. Next time please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead.

Comment: The path is relative to the application context. Thus the GET endpoint should also include the context name (usually the application name). Add the context name like this: `http://localhost:8080/<context_name>/api/countries/string`

Comment: That doesn´t work i tried to consume the endpoint over GET http://localhost:8080/TestServer/api/countries/string